# Getting Value from Captcha Div Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, captcha

I coded a little script to automate a quiz website. Before entering the quiz, you must log in with your email and solve a captcha. I would like to work with selenium and detect when the captcha is solved, so the process can continue automatically.

First:

```
<span class="recaptcha-checkbox goog-inline-block recaptcha-checkbox-unchecked rc-anchor-checkbox" role="checkbox" aria-checked="false" id="recaptcha-anchor" tabindex="0" dir="ltr" aria-labelledby="recaptcha-anchor-label">
<div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div>
<div class="recaptcha-checkbox-borderAnimation" role="presentation"></div>
<div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner" role="presentation"><div class="recaptcha-checkbox-spinner-overlay"></div></div>
<div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div>
</span>
```

Second:

```
<div class="recaptcha-checkbox-border" role="presentation"></div>
```

I've noticed that after solving the captcha the First span is changing in the `aria-checked='false'` - attribute. After solving it changes to `true`.

The second:
a new attribute named style is added.

I've tried to find the element with the Xpath:

```
checkbox = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span [@id='recaptcha-anchor']")
checkbox = driver.find_element(By.ID, "recaptcha-anchor")
```

I get this

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="recaptcha-anchor"]"}
```

I ve tried the code mentioned above: I also tried to work with

```
driver.execute_script
checked = "document.getElementsByID('recaptcha-anchor')[0]"
```

```
The link of the website: https://ridelikevoila.com/login
```

Comment: Can you share the URL of the site?

Comment: @Shawn If this isnt the right way to answer I am sorry, but I could find another way. I updated the question.
The link is: https://ridelikevoila.com/login

Answer (score 1):

To be very honest, I did not clearly understand the question. However, my assumption is that you are trying to click the `checkbox` which is shown below:

[image]

And while trying to click it, you are getting this error `Message: no such element: Unable to locate element`. If that is true, then below is the solution.

If you notice the HTML DOM clearly, you will see the presence of an IFRAME which is wrapping the desired element(highlighted checkbox). In such cases, you need to switch into the IFRAME first, then perform `click()` on the desired element. Refer the below code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# below line switches into the IFRAME
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']")))
# below line will click on the checkbox next to 'I'm not a robot'
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()
```

Imports required:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: Thank you, Shawn. 
This solution definitely helped me. But to clarify my question: I am manually solving the captcha. I want my program to detect the hock after me solving the captcha. Therefore, I tried to find changes in the code after I solved the captcha and found the changes, described in the main question. 
To specify the question: how can I get the value from "aria-checked:false". In order to compare it later with: if (value from aria-checked)== "true": (clicking submit button)
I will take a further look